# Dynamic Change JTable Header

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtableheader

I have a table displaying data for a year.  The table can have different periods for each column, e.g. weeks, bi-weeks, months.  I wish to change the year being displayed.  I have managed to get the table data and header to change, however, the structure of the table is lost.

The table is set up by this:

```
public class GenerateTable extends JTable {
private class RenderSelect extends JComponent implements TableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table,
            Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
            int column) {
        if ((row & 1)==0) {
            JCheckBox boxTemp = new JCheckBox();
            boxTemp.setSelected((boolean)value);
            return boxTemp;
        }
        else
            return new JTextField(" ");
    }

}
RenderSelect objRender = new RenderSelect();
public GenerateTable(GenerateTableModel model) {
    super(model);
    this.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    /*
     * Select
     */
    TableColumn colSelect = this.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
    colSelect.setPreferredWidth(70);
    colSelect.setMinWidth(40);
    colSelect.setCellRenderer(objRender);
    colSelect.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(new JCheckBox()));
    /*
     * category
     */
    this.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setResizable(false);
    this.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
    this.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setMinWidth(100);
    /*
     * Amount values
     */
    for (int i=2;i<model.getColumnCount();i++) {
        colSelect = this.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
        colSelect.setPreferredWidth(80);
        colSelect.setMinWidth(80);
        colSelect.setResizable(false);
    }
    setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
}
```

}

it gives me a layout like this:

[image]

I have the following code to change the year:

```
private void changeYears() {
    modGen.setYear(boxYears.getSelectedIndex()+1);
    modGen.fireTableStructureChanged();
    panMid.revalidate();
}
```

The table model (modGen) takes the year and returns the appropriate data in getColumnName and getValueAt based on the year.

When I use this the result is:

[image]

The table column widths are lost and the renderer for column 0 seems to have been dropped.  If I use fireTableDataChanged the header does not change but the data does.  Using fireTableStructureChanged does change the header but looses the structure as stated.

Any ideas?

Comment: what's `modGen` ?  show `modGen.setYear(boxYears.getSelectedIndex()+1);` method. Also show code for `GenerateTableModel`.

Comment: Read [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/AbstractTableModel.html#fireTableStructureChanged()), seems `table.setAutoCreateColumnsFromModel(false);` solve your problem.

Comment: I have tried getting the header and revalidating it:

Comment: post [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for help.

Comment: alex2410, I have set the flag as suggested and the header no longer changes.  If I post MCVE the size of the code will be hugh as the data model is quite complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must update the column model on changing header value

```
JTable table = new JTable(modGen);

//...

modGen.setYear(boxYears.getSelectedIndex()+1);
for (int i = 0; i < modGen.getColumnCount(); i++) {
  String name = modGen.getColumnName(i);
  int viewIdx = table.convertColumnIndexToView(i);
  if (viewIdx >= 0) {
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(viewIdx).setHeaderValue(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: please to add description about to convert column index from view to model (to avoids the mistakes from reordering)

Comment: @mKorbel It's already here: `int viewIdx = table.convertColumnIndexToView(i);`